# Question about Operator Method (Exponential Shift Rule)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Question:**
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-3\dfrac{dy}{dx}+2y=xe^x$$
**Solve using Method 4 (Operator method, and exponential Shift rule)**

First, here is the solution of the book:
$$y=\frac{1}{D^2-3D+2}xe^x=e^x\frac{1}{(D+1)^2-3(D+1)+2}x$$
$$y=e^x\frac{1}{D^2-D}x=-e^x\frac{1}{D}\frac{1}{1-D}x$$
$$y=-e^x(\frac{1}{D}+1+D+D^2+...)x \space\space\space\space (*)$$
$$y=-e^x(\frac{1}{2}x^2+x+1) \space\space\space\space (**)$$

My question is, how did we arrive at (*)? I assume we expanded $\frac{1}{1-D}$ then multiplied by $\frac{1}{D}$, which yields the answer. But, my solution was as follows:
$$y=-e^x\frac{1}{D}\frac{1}{1-D}x=-e^x\frac{1}{D}(1+D+D^2+...)x=-e^x\frac{1}{D}(x+1)$$
Which, after integration: $$y=-e^x(\frac{1}{2}x^2+x)\space\space\space\space (***)$$

Now, where did the +1 go (compare $(**)$ with $(***)$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely normal, the difference between these two solutions falls into the complementary or homogeneous solution. This method just computes one, particular solution of the inhomogeneous equation, and any solution can serve as such. The difference between two solutions always being a solution of the homogeneous equation.

If you switch to the Laplace transform, there you can include initial conditions in a systematic way, the general treatment is however the same as in this operator method.

Comment: Ah so I have to check the homogeneous equation answers and if a multiple is present as an addition/subtraction in the particular solution then it is okay; got it. Thanks a lot.